# xsi type and xsd tag

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I just want an xml output like this one:

```
<ranzcp_user xmlns:ns1="urn:logon">
<user_id  xsi:type="xsd:string">12345678</user_id>
<user_name xsi:type="xsd:string">JTestFloor</user_name>
<title xsi:type="xsd:string">Dr</title>
<first_name xsi:type="xsd:string">TestJoni</first_name>
<last_name xsi:type="xsd:string">TestFloor</last_name>
<email xsi:type="xsd:string">Joni.Floor2@test.com </email>
<organisation_identifier xsi:type="xsd:string">RANZCPAU</organisation_identifier>
```

I already have a wcf service for this, currently this is the base model im using to create those xml :

```
public class user
{
    public string user_id { get; set; }
    public string user_name { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string organisation_identifier { get; set; }
}
```

and a simple call to the service :

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public ranzcp_user UserData()
    {
        ranzcp_user data = new ranzcp_user();
        data.user_id = "12345678";
        data.user_name = "JTestFloor";
        data.title = "Dr";
        data.first_name = "TestJoni";
        data.last_name = "TestFloor";
        data.email = "Joni.Floor2@test.com";
        data.organisation_identifier = "RANZCPAU";

        return data;
    }
}
```

The interface :

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    ranzcp_user UserData();

    // TODO: Add your service operations here
}
```

Which then gives me for now an xml result like this:
[image]

Comment: It helps if you can explain the differences explicitly. You can then also search on that. See for example [How to add xsi:type attribute to an XML element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24381588/how-to-add-xsitype-attribute-to-an-xml-element).

Comment: Hi @CodeCaster thanks, honestly saying i dont know what do you mean by that, but i just want to add this xsi:type="xsd:string", just like saying that the entity was of string data type. thanks

Comment: @CharlesMager yep more of like this, but what i need is to put it in each of the element under <ranzcp_user xmlns:ns1="urn:logon">

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do this is to change the type of your properties to something less specific - then the serializer will insert the type attributes to identify the types.

```
public class ranzcp_user
{
    public object user_id { get; set; }
    public object user_name { get; set; }
    public object title { get; set; }
    public object first_name { get; set; }
    public object last_name { get; set; }
    public object email { get; set; }
    public object organisation_identifier { get; set; }
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xCwRPS) for a working demo.