# Specify xsi:type for array property

Tags: c#, wcf, xmlserializer

I'm writing a WCF service that uses XmlSerializer.  The service is an implementation based on WSDL and an XSD that was provided to me from the group who will be consuming the service.  Basically it's a data adapter between their system and mine.

One particular class has a property that is an array of another reference type defined in the project.  I need to specify `xsi:type` for this property.

I used svcutil to generate the code from the WSDL and XSD and then "fixed" the resulting code in a couple of places.  This property is one that I had to fix.

The class definition is (trimmed down to just the problem area):

```
[GeneratedCode("svcutil", "4.6.1055.0")]
[Serializable]
[DebuggerStepThrough]
[DesignerCategory("code")]
[XmlType(Namespace = "urn:example.com:types")]
public class userData
{
    private ItemType[] itemTypeField;

    [XmlArray(Order = 0, Namespace = "urn:example.com:types")]
    [XmlArrayItem("item", IsNullable = false, Type = typeof(ItemType), Namespace = "urn:example.com:types")]
    public ItemType[] myprop
    {
        get { return itemTypeField; }
        set { itemTypeField = value; }
    }
}
```

The XML that is produced when calling the service method is (`userData` is a property of the `getUserResponse` class):

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <getUserResponse xmlns="urn:example.com:types">
         <userData>
            <myprop>
               <item>
                  <key>some key</key>
                  <value>some value</value>
               </item>
               <item>
                  <key>some other key</key>
                  <value>some other value</value>
               </item>
            </myprop>
         </userData>
      </getUserResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I need the `<myprop>` element to look like this:

```
<myprop xsi:type="ns1:MapType"
    xmlns:ns1="urn:example.com:types"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

How can I get the XmlSerializer to generate the `xsi:type` for the array property `myprop`?

I've found these similar questions as the closest thing to my problem, but they don't apply to arrays:
[xsi type and xsd tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37224760/xml-xsi-type-and-xsd-tag)
[How can I force the use of an xsi:type attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943597/how-can-i-force-the-use-of-an-xsitype-attribute)

Do I need to do this with a custom serializer?

Please let me know if I need to post any of the service contract.  Everything else in the service is working just fine, it's just this little bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any way to do this using any of the builtin mechanisms (attributes, config, etc) so I ended up writing a custom message inspector to alter the XML on the fly before it's sent out in the response.  Here is the code:

Custom Ispector - Performs the XML rewrite to add the needed markup

```
using System.IO;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using System.Xml;

namespace MyProj
{
    public class CustomInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            if (reply.Headers.Action == "urn:example:wsdl/Adapter/getUserResponse")
            {
                MessageBuffer copy = reply.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue);
                XmlDictionaryReader xdr = copy.CreateMessage().GetReaderAtBodyContents();
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(xdr);
                xdr.Close();

                doc.InnerXml = doc.InnerXml.Replace(@"<myprop>",
                    @"<myprop xsi:type=""ns1:MapType"" xmlns:ns1=""urn:example.com:types"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"">");
                doc.InnerXml = doc.InnerXml.Replace(@"<item>", @"<item xmlns=""urn:example.com:types"">");

                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(ms);
                doc.Save(xw);
                xw.Flush();
                xw.Close();
                ms.Position = 0;
                XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(ms);


                Message newMsg = Message.CreateMessage(reply.Version, reply.Headers.Action, reader);
                reply = newMsg;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Custom Endpoint Behavior - attaches the new message inspector to the service endpoint:

```
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;

namespace MyProj
{
    public class CustomBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
    {
        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
        }

        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
            endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new CustomInspector());
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Custom Behavior Extension Element - defines the new behavior

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel.Configuration;

namespace KeypadIdmAdaptor
{
    public class CustomBehaviorExtensionElement : BehaviorExtensionElement
    {
        protected override object CreateBehavior()
        {
            return new CustomBehavior();
        }

        public override Type BehaviorType
        {
            get { return typeof(CustomBehavior); }
        }
    }
}
```

Wire it up in web.config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="CustomBehaviorExtension" type="MyProj.CustomBehaviorExtensionElement, MyProj, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <CustomBehaviorExtension />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="MyProj.MyService">
        <endpoint binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
        <endpoint name="MyServiceEndpoint" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyProjServiceContract"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

And here is the XML produced in the response message:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <getUserResponse xmlns="urn:example.com:types">
         <userData>
            <myProp xsi:type="ns1:MapType" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns1="urn:example.com:types">
               <item>
                  <key>some key</key>
                  <value>some value</value>
               </item>
               <item>
                  <key>some other key</key>
                  <value>some other value</value>
               </item>
            </myProp >
         </userData>
      </getUserResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```