# C# XML Serialization How To Set Attribute xsi:type

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

This is how my Xml should look after XML Serialization:

```
<value xsi:type="CD" otherAttributes= "IDK">
.
.
.
</value>
```

Thats my C# code to it:

```
public class Valué
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName ="xsi:type")]
    public string Type { get; set; } = "CD";
    [XmlAttribute(attributeName: "otherAttributes")]
    public string OtherAttributes { get; set; } = "IDK"
}
```

Apparently the XmlSerializer can't serialize colons (:) in attributenames.... how do i fix this problem?
If i remove the colon from the attributeName itm works out fine ..

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24381588/how-to-add-xsitype-attribute-to-an-xml-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it the correct way :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Valué value = new CD() { OtherAttributes = "IDK" };
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Valué));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value);

        }
    }
    [XmlInclude(typeof(CD))]
    public class Valué
    {
    }
    public class CD : Valué
    {
        [XmlAttribute(attributeName: "otherAttributes")]
        public string OtherAttributes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Davey van Tilburg : I don't know how anybody you get an answer from that link.  The answer is not very clear.

Comment: Oh damn sorry i meant to post that on the question, not the answer!