# WCF: Rename the xsi:type in XML

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap, ws

I am developing a SOAP service using WCF in C# to a specific set of requirements. I have to develop one method with that accept multiple types, and I achieved that. However, the requirements state the type attribute has to be named "BaseType". I can't find any docs on how to achieve this. Any idea here?

Current:

```
<Base xsi:type="locations" TransactionTime="2020-04-29T20:53:00">
</Base>
```

Desired:

```
<Base BaseType="locations" TransactionTime="2020-04-29T20:53:00">
    </Base>
```

Edit: 
Forgot to mention I have switched WCF to use XmlSerializerFormat to meet some other requirements of adding attributes to elements

Comment: See my answer at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61407681/c-sharp-xml-serialization-how-to-set-attribute-xsitype/61408192#61408192

Comment: @jdweng I'm not sure if you understood the question? This doesn't help rename the attribute

Comment: You can't do what you desire.  Xml Serializer is not designed that way.  I completely understand your question.  You must leave the xml the way it is.